# How correct use siblings on anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().hide()
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

a {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<ul>
  <li><a>one</a></li><br><br>
  <li><a>two</a></li><br><br>
  <li><a>three</a></li><br><br>
</ul>
```

i click anyone anchor other brother element not hide.

but change make $("a") to  $("li") is work . why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element `a` has no sibling, its the only child of `li`.

In order to hide the other `li`s, you should use sibling on them:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  $(this).parents("li").siblings().hide()
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<ul>
  <li><a>one</a></li><br><br>
  <li><a>two</a></li><br><br>
  <li><a>three</a></li><br><br>
</ul>
```

Comment: element a has no sibling. what element same no sibling? or only element a ?

Comment: siblings are all the element at the same 'level' in the DOM tree: all the element with the same parent. The only child of each `<li>` is an `<a>` element